# How to find the value of this limit? $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}n\int_0^1 nx^{n-1}\left(\frac{1}{1+x}-\frac{1}{2}\right)\mathrm dx.$

Tags: calculus, limits

How to calculate the following limit:
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}n\int_0^1 nx^{n-1}\left(\frac{1}{1+x}-\frac{1}{2}\right)\mathrm dx.$$

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The integral is equal to (via Mathematica):

$$I(n)=\int_0^1 nx^{n-1}\left(\frac{1}{1+x}-\frac{1}{2}\right)\mathrm dx.=(1/2)\left(-1 - n\psi( n/2) + n\psi((1 + n)/2)\right)$$

Where $\psi(z):=\frac{\Gamma'(z)}{\Gamma(z)}$ is the PolyGamma function.

The limit is equal to (via Mathematica):

$$\lim_{n\to\infty} n I(n)=\frac{1}{4}$$

-mike

Comment: What is $\psi$ ?

Answer (score 8):

Use the substitution $x^n=t$.
$$n\int_0^1 nx^{n-1}\left(\frac{1}{1+x}-\frac{1}{2}\right)\,dx=n\int_0^1 \left(\frac{1}{1+t^{1/n}}-\frac{1}{2}\right)\,dt$$
$$\Rightarrow \lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} n\int_0^1 \left(\frac{1}{1+t^{1/n}}-\frac{1}{2}\right)\,dt=\lim_{h\rightarrow 0}\dfrac{\displaystyle \int_0^1 \left(\dfrac{1}{1+t^{h}}-\frac{1}{2}\right)\,dt}{h}$$
Use L'Hopital's rule and Leibniz rule to get:
$$\lim_{h\rightarrow 0}\int_0^1 \frac{-t^h\ln t}{(1+t^h)^2}\,dt=-\frac{1}{4}\int_0^1\ln t \,dt=\boxed{\dfrac{1}{4}}$$

Comment: nice! $dt$ is missing in the last two integrals

Comment: @mike: Oops, Thanks! :D

Answer (score 8):

My intuition in this situation is to integrate by parts, because we can use it to get rid of the factor of $n$ that we don't like. So use $u=\frac{1}{1+x}-1/2$ and $dv=nx^{n-1} dx$, then the boundary terms will cancel (check this!) and we will be left with

$$n \int_0^1 \frac{x^n}{(1+x)^2} dx$$

Introducing a factor of $n+1$ for convenience, we have

$$\frac{n}{n+1} \int_0^1 \frac{(n+1) x^n}{(1+x)^2} dx$$

We again integrate by parts, with a similar substitution as before. We get

$$\frac{n}{n+1} \left ( 1/4 - \int_0^1 \frac{-2 x^{n+1}}{(1+x)^3} dx \right )$$

(Check the boundary term yourself). It is not hard to show, by comparing to the integral of $2x^{n+1}$, that this last integral goes to zero as $n \to \infty$, and $\frac{n}{n+1} \to 1$ as $n \to \infty$, so the desired limit is $1/4$.

If you are in or have taken real analysis, then I think it is an instructive exercise with uniform convergence to show that if you replace $\frac{1}{1+x}-1/2$ with any continuous function $f$ so that $f(1)=0$ and $f'(1)$ exists, the limit will be $-f'(1)$. (So even though the example looks weird and complicated, it is in a certain sense "natural".) If this is actually for calculus as the tags suggest then please disregard this remark.

Answer (score 2):

$\newcommand{\+}{^{\dagger}}
 \newcommand{\angles}[1]{\left\langle\, #1 \,\right\rangle}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\, #1 \,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\, #1 \,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\ceil}[1]{\,\left\lceil\, #1 \,\right\rceil\,}
 \newcommand{\dd}{{\rm d}}
 \newcommand{\down}{\downarrow}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,{\rm e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\fermi}{\,{\rm f}}
 \newcommand{\floor}[1]{\,\left\lfloor #1 \right\rfloor\,}
 \newcommand{\half}{{1 \over 2}}
 \newcommand{\ic}{{\rm i}}
 \newcommand{\iff}{\Longleftrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\imp}{\Longrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\isdiv}{\,\left.\right\vert\,}
 \newcommand{\ket}[1]{\left\vert #1\right\rangle}
 \newcommand{\ol}[1]{\overline{#1}}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\, #1 \,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\pp}{{\cal P}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\vphantom{\large A}\,#2\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\sech}{\,{\rm sech}}
 \newcommand{\sgn}{\,{\rm sgn}}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{{\rm d}^{#1} #2}{{\rm d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\ul}[1]{\underline{#1}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\, #1 \,\right\vert}
 \newcommand{\wt}[1]{\widetilde{#1}}$
$\ds{\lim_{n \to \infty}\bracks{%
    n\int_{0}^{1}nx^{n - 1}\pars{{1 \over 1+x} - \half}\,\dd x}:\ {\large ?}}$

> \begin{align}\color{#c00000}{\lim_{n \to \infty}\bracks{%
> n\int_{0}^{1}nx^{n - 1}\pars{{1 \over 1 + x} - \half}\,\dd x}}
> =\lim_{n \to \infty}\bracks{%
>     n^{2}\color{#00f}{\int_{0}^{1}{x^{n - 1} \over 1 + x}\,\dd x} - \half\,n}
> \tag{1}
> \end{align}

\begin{align}&\color{#00f}{\int_{0}^{1}{x^{n - 1} \over 1 + x}\,\dd x}
=\int_{0}^{1}{1 \over 1 + x}\,\dd x - \int_{0}^{1}{1 - x^{n - 1} \over 1 + x}
\,\dd x
\\[3mm]&=\ln\pars{2}
-\pars{\int_{0}^{1}{1 - x^{n - 1} \over 1 + x}\,\dd x
+\int_{0}^{1}{1 - x^{n - 1} \over 1 - x}\,\dd x}
+\int_{0}^{1}{1 - x^{n - 1} \over 1 - x}\,\dd x
\\[3mm]&=\ln\pars{2}
-2\int_{0}^{1}{1 - x^{n - 1} \over 1 - x^{2}}\,\dd x
+\int_{0}^{1}{1 - x^{n - 1} \over 1 - x}\,\dd x
\\[3mm]&=\ln\pars{2}
-2\int_{0}^{1}{1 - x^{\pars{n - 1}/2} \over 1 - x}\,\half\,x^{-1/2}\,\dd x
+\int_{0}^{1}{1 - x^{n - 1} \over 1 - x}\,\dd x
\\[3mm]&=\ln\pars{2}
+\int_{0}^{1}{1 - x^{-1/2} \over 1 - x}\,\dd x
-\int_{0}^{1}{1 - x^{n/2 - 1} \over 1 - x}\,\dd x
+\int_{0}^{1}{1 - x^{n - 1} \over 1 - x}\,\dd x
\\[3mm]&=\ln\pars{2} + \bracks{\Psi\pars{\half} + \gamma}
-\bracks{\Psi\pars{n \over 2} + \gamma}
+\bracks{\Psi\pars{n} + \gamma}
\end{align}
where we used the [identity](http://people.math.sfu.ca/~cbm/aands/page_259.htm) ${\bf\mbox{6.3.22}}$.

> With the
>   [identity](http://people.math.sfu.ca/~cbm/aands/page_258.htm) ${\bf\mbox{6.3.3}}$, we find:
>   $$
> \color{#00f}{\int_{0}^{1}{x^{n - 1} \over 1 + x}\,\dd x}
> =-\ln\pars{2} - \Psi\pars{n \over 2}
> +\Psi\pars{n}
> $$

With the [Digamma Asymptotic Expansion](http://people.math.sfu.ca/~cbm/aands/page_259.htm) ${\bf\mbox{6.3.18}}$, the last expression is reduced to:
\begin{align}&\left.\color{#00f}{\int_{0}^{1}{x^{n - 1} \over 1 + x}
\,\dd x\,}\right\vert_{n\ \gg 1}
\\[3mm]&=-\ln\pars{2} - \bracks{\ln\pars{n \over 2} - {1 \over n} - {1 \over 3n^{2}}}
+ \bracks{\ln\pars{n} - {1 \over 2n} - {1 \over 12n^{2}}}
+ {\rm O}\pars{1 \over n^{4}}
\\[3mm]&={1 \over 2n} + \color{#c00000}{\large{1 \over 4}}\,{1 \over n^{2}} + {\rm O}\pars{1 \over n^{4}}
\end{align}

> such that ( see expression $\pars{1}$ ):
>   $$\color{#66f}{\large%
> \lim_{n \to \infty}\bracks{%
> n\int_{0}^{1}nx^{n - 1}\pars{{1 \over 1+x} - \half}\,\dd x}}
> =\color{#66f}{\large{1 \over 4}}
> $$